# Partially non-editable textarea

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

Here is my desired template for my textarea

[image]

Now, How can I make the template text(the Subjective, Objective..) non editable? I am doing this to maintain one column in database instead of four.

Here is my sample code onload:

```
TextBox1.Text = "Subjective Findings: " & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "Objective Findings:  " & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & ""
```

Design:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="500px"  BackColor="#f5fbff"    TextMode="MultiLine" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="LightSkyBlue" BorderWidth="1px" Rows="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You should have 4 `textarea`, and combine it in your server code

Comment: I can do that, but the problem now is about the fetching of data from database to the 4 textarea.

Comment: What is your program design? How you store your data?

Comment: for now, that textarea saves into 1 column in sql server, and retrieves it as it is. Now my problem is, the users might erase or backspace the texts stated above, so, I just wanted it to be not editable.

Comment: the problem is how you store your data? you store something like "Subjective:abcObjective:abcAssessment:Plan:"? or you store "abcabc"? That is how your program design.

Comment: I am storing it like the first one you stated "Subjective:abcObjective:abcAssessment:Plan:". But i can change it if needed though.

Comment: So how your screen design? for `textarea`, you cannot fix the text position, which means when you load the data, it will show "Subjective:abcObjective:abcAssessment:Plan:" but not the layout you provide

Comment: post your code... This is doable. we can help you.

Comment: edited and added some code behind and design code

Comment: why downvote :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is impossible to have a non editable text inside a textbox, so I my fix is to separate the saving part of the 4 and add a placeholder for each textbox